# How does one use SELECT CASE within a Scalar Function?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Here is a very basic Scalar Function which should return `1` if the sum of the 2 provided numbers is equal to `10` or `0` if not.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsSumEqualToTen
(
    @number1 INT,
    @number2 INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN (@number1 + @number2) = 10
        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END
    )
```

However, instead I get a syntax error!

> Incorrect syntax near 'RETURN'.

What is incorrect here?

Comment: `RETURNS BIT` declares a multistep scalar function. `as return` signifies an inline table-valued function. Pick one or another. It is better for performance if you choose inline table-valued by using `returns table` and giving a name to the selected column. Otherwise, give the function a body with `begin...end` and have a `return` inside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `SELECT` in the body of the function.  You can simply write:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsSumEqualToTen (
    @number1 INT,
    @number2 INT
) RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (CASE WHEN (@number1 + @number2) = 10 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END);
END
```

Comment: Not sure where `IN (10, 0)` came from, but the OP requested what you would expect from `IsSumEqualToTen`: `return case when @number1 + @number2 = 10 then 1 else 0 end;`. As GSerg and Alan Burstein pointed out, there is no need to `cast` when the function return type is declared as `bit`.

Comment: @Habo . . . I don't feel like I made it up, but I'm not sure where it did come from.  I think it is more important that there is no need for a *`select`*.

Answer (score 2):

You need a BEGIN/END

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsSumEqualToTen
(
    @number1 INT,
    @number2 INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN (@number1 + @number2) IN (10,0)
        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END
    )
END
GO
```

Also note that you don't need to cast as a BIT since the function returns a bit. Lastly, scalar functions are slow as dirt. You can use an inline function instead which requires a little extra effort to apply but will be several times faster.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsSumEqualToTen
(
    @number1 INT,
    @number2 INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT is10 = CASE WHEN (@number1 + @number2) =IN (10,0) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE 0 END;
GO
```

Comment: Ah, I had wondered why I had been seeing examples online of `CREATE FUNCTION` without the `BEGIN` and `END` and just figured it was shorthand for a single-statement scalar function.  I'm actually trying to figure out why I'm getting a syntax error for using a CTE `WITH` in a scalar function (even with `BEGIN` and `END`).  This does at least eliminate the red-herring of the `SELECT CASE` appearing to have been the culprit.